# Is it okay to have a modal window with a button that redirects to another page?

Tags: navigation, modal-windows, modal, redirect

[image]

In my case, the information written in the modal window is not directly linked to the button. That is, the button is not some action that the user does after reading the information given in the modal. Rather, the button stands for an add on feature of the entity (modal window entity) and so it redirects the user to an entirely different page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's extremely common. In most cases, the modal would have the equivalent of OK and Cancel buttons (albeit with different labels) with the OK leading to a new page and the Cancel closing the modal and staying on the same page. In your case, it looks like you'd have the primary action button at the bottom leading to the new page, and the close/cancel button at the top staying on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in case for what it is used, I would say.
(a little benchmarking on this use case could clear it up)

Thinking as the user I could say:
As a user I want to be informed in case I get redirected.
As a user I want to fill that I am doing the right thing.

Possible Structure:

- Closing function
- Cheering and situation representativ visualisation ( Icon, Gif, IMG…)
- Cheering text about where I am about to go
- Body text
- Cheering button  ("Let's go")
- Optional timer with automatic redirect after x sec.

How did it went with yours?

Comment: Hi Kim-Canan,
I am not sure what you mean with cheering.